# What is the quickest way in python to compute inner(dot) product of normalized document vectors?

Tags: python, pandas

Document vectors in dictionary form is like this.

{'abcd':0.4531,
'hhks':0.08763,
'djlkl':9843
}

Length of the vector can vary.
I have tried pandas Series.
However I have seen that in case of smaller vectors pandas was about 100 times slower than a dictionary implementation.
Is there a better way for doing this?

### Code using dictionaries

length of d1 is always less than length of d2

```
def cosine_smaller_larger(d1, d2):
    s = 0.0
    for key in d1.keys():
        if key in d2:
            s += d1[key] * d2[key]
    return s
```

### Code using pandas

```
from pandas import Series

def seriesmult(s1, s2):
    return s1.mul(s2, fill_value=0).sum()

def cosine_smaller_larger(d1, d2):
    s1 = Series(d1)
    s2 = Series(d2)
    return seriesmult(s1, s2)
```

### Code used to profile the above two method(I am ignoring the time taken to create pandas Series)

```
def cosine_smaller_larger_comparison(d1, d2):
    t1 = time.time()
    s = 0.0
    for key in d1.keys():
        if key in d2:
            s += d1[key] * d2[key]
    t2 = time.time()
    t3 = t2 - t1

    s1 = Series(d1)
    s2 = Series(d2)
    t1 = time.time()
    ss = s1.mul(s2, fill_value=0).sum()
    t2 = time.time()
    t4 = t2 - t1
    try:
        t5 = t4 / t3
    except:
        t5 = 'division by zero'
    intersection = set(d1.keys()) & set(d2.keys())
    num_mult = len(intersection)
    ld1 = len(d1)
    ld2 = len(d2)
    output = "L1 = {}, L2 = {}, Mults = {}, PT<DT? = {}, PT = {}, DT = {}, PT/DT = {}".format(ld1, ld2, num_mult, t4 < t3, t4, t3, t5)
    print output

    return s
```

### Case1: Large vector(L1 > 1000)

I converted the output of cosine_smaller_larger_comparison as a pandas dataframe for checking what is the behavior for large vectors.

```
L1 = length of first vector
L2 = length of the second vector
Mults = number of non zero multiplictions
PT = time taken by pandas
DT = time taken by dictionary implementation
PTdivDT = the factor by which dictionary beats pandas
PTltDT=Was Pandas faster than dictionary for this particular vector



(Pdb) df1.loc[df1['L1']>1000][:10]
              DT    L1     L2  Mults        PT   PTdivDT PTltDT
64002   0.000145  1064   1361    151  0.001333  9.195724  False
64308   0.000168  1064   1853    178  0.001125  6.692199  False
64362   0.000197  1044   1064    148  0.001260  6.397094  False
108372  0.000180  1018   1064    167  0.001298  7.210596  False
113457  0.001332  3141   9644   3141  0.003576  2.685106  False
113458  0.002342  3886   9083   3886  0.004181  1.785198  False
113583  0.002099  3435   9644   3433  0.003591  1.710813  False
113584  0.002662  4101   9083   4095  0.003828  1.437937  False
113592  0.000887  1853  19674   1850  0.005778  6.514785  False
113619  0.002480  3198   9644   3193  0.003207  1.293337  False
```

Here dictionary implementation beats pandas series, but the margin is less.

### Case2: Smaller vectors

Here are some input sizes for which pandas was more than 100 times slower.

```
(Pdb) df1.loc[df1['PTdivDT']>100][:30]
          DT  L1   L2  Mults        PT     PTdivDT PTltDT
0   0.000002   3    3      0  0.001242  651.250000  False
1   0.000002   3    3      0  0.000558  292.625000  False
6   0.000003   3    4      1  0.000341  110.000000  False
8   0.000001   0    0      0  0.000106  111.000000  False
10  0.000001   0   30      0  0.000362  379.750000  False
18  0.000001   1    3      0  0.000339  284.200000  False
19  0.000000   1    3      0  0.000341         inf  False
24  0.000001   1    3      0  0.000381  399.500000  False
26  0.000000   0    0      0  0.000103         inf  False
28  0.000003  29   30      0  0.000399  128.769231  False
31  0.000004  12   20      5  0.000409  100.941176  False
32  0.000003   8  156      4  0.000377  121.615385  False
33  0.000002  11  369      0  0.000410  214.875000  False
34  0.000002   1    1      1  0.000202  105.875000  False
35  0.000003   2   60      2  0.000349  112.615385  False
36  0.000001   1    3      0  0.000335  351.250000  False
37  0.000001   1    3      0  0.000325  272.600000  False
39  0.000003  17   32      2  0.000389  136.000000  False
41  0.000003  11   18      4  0.000386  124.538462  False
42  0.000001   3    5      0  0.000332  348.250000  False
44  0.000001   0    0      0  0.000102  107.000000  False
46  0.000004  30   42      0  0.000471  116.235294  False
51  0.000010  59  369      2  0.001014  101.261905  False
54  0.000001   1    3      0  0.000518  543.250000  False
55  0.000001   1    3      0  0.000526  551.750000  False
57  0.000004  11   32      2  0.000461  113.705882  False
60  0.000001   1    3      0  0.000660  692.250000  False
62  0.000001   0    2      0  0.000293  307.000000  False
64  0.000003  26   30      0  0.000343  110.692308  False
65  0.000002   1    1      1  0.000223  116.875000  False
```

Comment: take a look at [pairwise_distances](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html). you increase n_jobs to compute the similarity matrix in parallel. you just need to change your data representation

Comment: Thanks for giving me this info. I was not aware of the n_jobs option in pairwise_distances.